# Make a function that reads (string) input

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and I have an assignment to **make a function that reads a name**. For some reason the following *'solution'* does not work and the output is always something with weird *chinese?* characters. What went wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input(char* a);

int main()
{
    char name[8];

    input(&name);

    printf("%s", name);

    return 0;
}

void input(char* a)
{
    char buff[8];

    scanf("%s", buff);

    *a = buff;
}
```

Comment: You are falling into one of the classical rookie mistakes - trying to use a **local** outside a function (`*a = buff;` does **not** copy the string!)

Comment: @YePhIcK So what would be the correct approach? Maybe use a double pointer ( `void input(char** a);` ) ?

Comment: On top of everything else said here, consider making that buff/name array larger than 8. Maybe 10-20. It can be a source of future bugs and issues. My own name is longer than that :)

Comment: An 8-byte buffer is asking for trouble. `scanf` is asking for trouble. A lot of this is nothing but trouble. Use [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) where you can limit how much data you read from input. `scanf` can and will explode if the data can't fit.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in your

```
    *a = buff;
```

statement because `buff` does not have a life outside of your function. so its memory will be lost.. so it is not safe to try and use buff in this way...

[ But as pointed out by @pablo what `*a = buff;` will do is copy the address of `buff` and put it into the memory allocated to `a`, which is really not what you want to do. ]

below should work and do include `return` from your function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input(char* a);

int main()
{
    char name[8];

    input(&name);

    printf("%s", name);

    return 0;
}

void input(char* a)
{
   // char buff[8];

    scanf("%s", a);

  //  *a = buff;
    return;
}
```

one other point is to check if you are sure the name will only be 8 characters long... why not have it as 50 characters?

Comment: Your first statement is not quite correct (I know that was the OP's intention), but `*a = buff` is assigning the address pointed to by `buff` in the memory pointed to by `a`.

Comment: `input()` return type is of `void` type then why `return` at last in the `input()` function.

Comment: @achal - have a look at 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003283/returning-from-a-void-function   there is a whole question devoted to this issue of return or not from a void function

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should pass the array to the function `input()` not its address. Secondly, replace `scanf("%s", buff)` with `scanf("%s", a)`. This will store the string directly in the array you pass to the function.

So, the fixed code should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input(char* a);

int main(void)
{
    char name[8];

    input(name);

    printf("%s\n", name);

    return 0;
}

void input(char* a)
{
    scanf("%s", a);
}
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is that, you try to assign address of the local array `buff` to the first element of the array that you pass to the function. This shouldn't even compile or the compiler must issue a warning! If your compiler allows it to pass without any of these, that's a disaster.

Finally, the `main` function should be declared as `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: My compiler actually warns. And I honestly never saw the main(void) concept, including in the many books and online.

Comment: @atru `int main(void)` is one of the 3 possible 'main` combinations. If your compiler warns about it, then is something wrong with your compiler. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Pablo I got that, I was just questioning the need for int main(void) and it's superiority over int main(). The third one without using arguments doesn't makes much sense either. Unfortunately clang but I'm pretty sure I had warnings-only on gcc too..

Comment: The difference between `int foo();` and `int bar(void)` is that you can pass arguments to `foo`, with `bar` the compiler won't let you pass arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`*a = buff;`  doesn't copy `buff` to `a`. Use `strcpy()` as

```
strcpy(a,buff);
```

complete code :

```
void input(char* a);
int main()
{
        char name[8];
        //input(&name);/** no need to pass & bcz name itself represents address */
        input(name);
        printf("[%s]", name);
        return 0;
}
void input(char* a) {
        char buff[8];
        scanf("%s", buff);
        //*a = buff; /* not valid **/
        strcpy(a,buff);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function is a problem:

```
void input(char* a)
{
    char buff[8];

    scanf("%s", buff);

    *a = buff;
}
```

`buff` is local variable that is only valid while `input()` is running, so
returning this variable is wrong.

`*a = buff;` is also wrong. `*a` is the same as `a[0]`, that means it is a
`char`. `buff` is an array of `char`, so you are assigning a pointer to an array
of `char` to a `char` variable. That doesn't sound right, it's putting apples in
the oranges box. In fact what is happening is that you are assigning the address
pointed to by `buff` in the memory pointed to by `a`.
Your compiler should have warned you about that, don't ignore the
compiler warnings, they are there to help you, not annoy you,

```
void input(char *a)
{
    scanf("%s", a);
}
```

would be the correct function.

Doing

```
char name[8];

input(&name);
```

is wrong, even though the address of `name` and `&name` will be the same, but
they will have different types. `name` decays into a pointer, so it is a
`char*`. However `&name` is a pointer to an array of `char`, a different type.
The compiler should give you a warning like this:

> warning: passing argument 1 of `bar` from incompatible pointer type
>   note: expected `char *` but argument is of type `char (*)[8]`

The correct call is:

```
input(name);
```

In general there is one big problem, though: You only declare 8 spaces for the
buffer. If the name is longer than 7 characters, you will have a buffer
overflow. Instead of using `scanf` I recommend using `fgets` instead, because
here you have much more control of the input and the memory boundaries.

```
char name[30];
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0; // removing possible newline
```

`scanf` is not always easy to use. A name can be long and have spaces in it.
Specially for a beginner, this can be tricky. `fgets` is easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the address of `name` since it's a char array. And when you do the copy in `input()`, you should use `strcpy`. The following code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void input(char* a);

int main()
{
  char name[8];

  input(name);

  printf("%s", name);

  return 0;
}

void input(char* a)
{
  char buff[8];

  scanf("%s", buff);

  strcpy(a, buff);
}
```