# Is a return statement always necessary?

Tags: c, return

What is the difference between:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int x){
    return x*x - 3;
}

int main(){
    int x = 4;
    printf("f(%d) = %d\n", x, f(x));
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int x){
    x*x - 3;
}

int main(){
    int x = 4;
    printf("f(%d) = %d\n", x, f(x));
    return 0;
}
```

Because the two compile without error (using gcc) and the two are working.
Is the first return really important?

Comment: If you want to return a value, yes, you must explicitly return it.  It's an accident if it seems to work without it.

Comment: `return` is not a _fonction_.

Comment: It is absolutely necessary.

Comment: It depends where in the main it's necessary but if a function is declared as void you dont even Need a return but in every other function `int, double...` you Need the return value

Comment: MSVC gives **two** warnings: "'-': operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect" and "'f': must return a value". So crank up your warning levels (or take them seriously if they were given).

Comment: @SouravGhosh return could be a fonction. You don't know.

Comment: @nicomp oh right, poor me (_goes and sulks in a corner..._)

Comment: If you want to see how this is abused horribly, look into code golf where you will see the "per compiler" rules for how it treats a functions without a return.  If you do not use a return statement (outside of main) you are invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: @SouravGhosh actually, you cannot return a function type. You can return a pointer to a function, but not a function. So you were correct :) come back from the corner.

Comment: many c compilers dont warn about this on their default settings. It should really be an unconditional fatal

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Even a void function needs a return statement?

Comment: @nicomp nope, it does not.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I didn't think so, but above is written " If you do not use a return statement (outside of main) you are invoking undefined behaviour."

Comment: @nicomp read it the other way, if you're trying to use the return value from a function which has a `void` return type, you're in trouble already. :) I guess that assumes a no-void returning function.

Comment: @nicomp [see this also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9003283/2173917).

Comment: @SouravGhosh Makes sense. Now I will research "fonction" and write a scholarly paper on it.

Comment: @user12346352 `main` is the one function of non-`void` type that need not `return` anything: in this case the compiler will add `return 0;`

Comment: @nicomp [here's something to get you started with](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_(math%C3%A9matiques)).

Answer (score 7):

The second snippet invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

A function, which reaches the ending `}` and the return value is used in the caller, invokes undefined behavior.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.9.1

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.

So, yes, for a function

- returning anything other than `void` (and whose value is going to be used in caller), must include a `return` statement with an expression, which has a
  type same as the return type of the function.
- returning `void`, can have a `return` statement without any expression. However, [this can be also be omitted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9003283/2173917) without any trouble.

*Note: Just because "your" compiler (settings) complies the code and produces a binary, does not mean the code is right. Use all the warning flags and strict checks, they will save you lots of trouble*.

Comment: I know if the compiler compile, it is not necessary right. But I had not explicit warning, that's why I asked the question. Thank you :) (last edit with clang there is a warning. I was using gcc and tcc (to test) with no warnings). I searched but I didn't really understand, know yes thank you.

Comment: - > naguam when in doubt, use the highest level of strict checking. As mentioned in the comment by @weathervane, you should have seen the warnings already.

Comment: @naguam: Since the behavior is *undefined*, the compiler is not required to issue any sort of diagnostic if you forget the `return` statement.  Most will if you raise the warning level, though.

Comment: doesn't the result of the last line get sent as the return value when no explicit return statement is mentioned?

Comment: @DivakarRajesh nope, not according to the C standard..

Comment: (Coming from a recent dup:) I would emphasize that it is perfectly OK for non-void functions **in C** to return without a `return`. The responsibility is strictly with the caller to not use that non-value, and it is a run-time problem: When a branch has been executed which `return`ed a value the caller can use it, if not, then not. That even makes sense: A caller may know when a value is impossible to compute and call a function only for the side effects.

Comment: @DivakarRajesh Some languages do that, e.g. Alogol68. The C comma operator has that semantic as well.