# calculate the sum of 1 array using recursion with only 1 entry in c

Tags: c

just like thet title says i need the sum of the array using recursion and it's not working .

```
int somme_elements(int t[10])
{   int static i = -1 ;
    if (i<10)
    {
        i++;
        return t[i] + somme_elements(t+1);
    }

}

int main()
{
  int t[10]={0} ; int i = 0 ;
  /*saisie_tableau(t);/*
  /*afficher_tableau(t);*/
  printf("la somme des valeur du tableau t est %d    ",somme_elements(t));
   return 0;
}
```

the last printf is supposed to print the sum value . but it's always a really big number or just doesn't make any sense .
thank you guys

Comment: When `i` is `9` you enter the `if` block, increment `i` and try to access `t[10]` which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int somme_elements(int t[10])
{   int static i = -1 ;
    if (i<10)
    {
        i++;
        return t[i] + somme_elements(t);
    } else return 0;
}
```

If `i<10` is true, just call the function again and the incremented static i will point the next item.
If `i<10` is false, the function will return 0, null for addition.

Note: I just keep the original question indent and format (in 2021-01-16).

Comment: But I don't like to use static variables to that!

Comment: thanks it works . could you please explain to me why i had to add the else return 0 ? i don't really need it i think .since the first if should do the trick . thanks

Comment: Well, if you don't use return, the compiler can return an undesirable value...
In C, better and easy to specify a return!
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003283/returning-from-a-void-function)

Comment: but if i return 0 . doesn't it mean that the first return doesn't count anymore ?

Comment: i still have a issue with the notion of the return in  recursion . because sometimes with ot without the first return the loop works just fine .

Comment: No! Only the last call will be 0! That is the magic of recursion!

Comment: To understand recursive function, I think about 2 cases: base and recursive cases. So I give a return to each case... (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-recursion-works-explained-with-flowcharts-and-a-video-de61f40cb7f9/)